# Initializing an input field with props value in react

Tags: reactjs

I've got a child component that has a text input field whose value should be initialized with props from parent component (`this.props.index`).

This should be controlled input, since I want to be able to store the text of the input.

Now, if I set the value to the state's attribute, whenever the component gets re-rendered, it's never updated, since setState is never called:

```
<input type={"text"} placeholder={"Index"} className={"form-control"}
                       value={this.state.index} onChange={this.updateStudentIndex}/>
```

On the other hand, if I set the value to the prop's attribute, it's fixed and changes cannot be made:

```
<input type={"text"} placeholder={"Index"} className={"form-control"}
                       value={this.props.index} onChange={this.updateStudentIndex}/>
```

How can I both initialize the state with `this.props.index`, and still be able to track changes in the input's value `this.state.index`?

Edit: Initialization should be done in async mode, i.e. when I click a button from the parent component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, this should not be done with controlled components, rather [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values)

Answer (score 3):

I think [default values](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values) might be helpful here.

Comment: Nope, this does not help. 
I got the following error:
`EditStudentDetails contains an input of type text with both value and defaultValue props. Input elements must be either controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the defaultValue prop, but not both).`

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with `The Component Lifecycle`, use `componentWillReceiveProps`, and set there then new `state`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if(this.props.index !== nextProps.index) {
     this.setState({index: nextProps.index})
   }
}
```

And you can hold your value in `state`, so on `componentWillMount` set your `state.index` to `props.index`

Comment: componentWillUpdate(){
        this.setState({index: this.props.index})
    } causes Maximum Update Depth Exceeded exception

Comment: Isn't componentWillReceiveProps going to be deprecated soon and shouldn't be used?

Answer (score 0):

In the `constructor` read the value from `props` and set that to `state`, this way you will get the `props.index` and maintain the changes in the `state` afterword. In the `onChange` event handler you can update `index` with the current value.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: props.index
    }
  }
  ...
  render() {
    const { index } = this.state;
    ...
  }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Sadly no, because the constructor is called when the child component is  first created, but I need the initializing to be asynchronously, i.e. when I click the button, the input fields are initialized.

Comment: Oh, but you didn't mention about `asynchronously initializing` in the question also nothing about `button` either :) ...

Comment: True, sorry. You got any other solution?

Comment: Nope, can you please share more detail, how the parent and child related and when you are initializing the child component. If possible share some code.

Comment: I found a solution, it lies with uncontrolled components.